# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of continous variable function

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Basically I am given a function $P_{l,k}$ where P is continuous and hermitian in $l$ and $k$ i.e. $P_{l,k}^*=P_{k,l}$.
What is the general procedure to find its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions? There must be some way of generalizing the meaning of a determinant to continuous functions, but I can't find anything in the literature.

Comment: First: you mean $\;P\;$ is *a linear operator*, right? Second, what is $\;l\;$ ? Some space, I guess...the space of all real sequences or what? Define it, we can't guess...still. Third, what do you mean by "continuous"? You're apparently using some topology on $\;l\;$ ...or somewhere: something about Hilbert or Banach spaces or what?

Comment: yes. P is a linear operator. Unfortunately I am not a mathematician (just a physicist) so my maths terminology is not great. but perhaps it would be better to write $P_{k,l}$ as $P(k,l)$. $k$ and $l$ are real variables. By continuous I meant that $k$ and $l$ don't take discrete values like in matrices.

Comment: You still haven't yet said on what linear space is $\;P\;$ acting...! If it is a finite dimensional one then via matrices, characteristic polynomial, etc. one can do something. Otherwise it may be harder. You being a physicist isn't a good justification to be sloppy as physicists study high mathematics (calculus, **linear algebra** , complex analysis, etc.)

Comment: well actually P(k,l) are actually the elements of a density "matrix". So it is not acting on anything.

Comment: That doesn't even make sense, because if it isn't acting on anything then how you expect to find eigenvectors??

Comment: well i have an equation like: $\int dk dl P(k,l)\ket{k}\bra{l}$ shouldn't it be possible to diagonalize this?

Comment: sorry i can't edit comments yet so: $\int dk dl P(k,l) |l\rangle \lrangle k|$